# task runner/queue/scheduling on openshift with django

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, openshift, ironworker

few days ago I have asked how to [send email with django and openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020272/sending-weekly-emails-using-django-and-openshift), but I guess it was too broad since it was closed.
So in this question I would like to know what **task runner/queue/scheduling system** should I use in general for django and openshift. Unfortunately I have not seen any tutorial for django and openshift.
Looks like **celery** is too complex to install easily on openshift.
Here are few [tasks django-packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/).
And openshift also provides **IronWorker** as scheduling app in marketplace. I tried to add free edition to my app, but I struggle setting it up.

So my question is, **what queue system should I use with django and openshift**? What do you use on openshift? Currently I only need to send personalised weekly emails, but my app works with few api providers and relatively large data, so I might use it more in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no iron/openshift guide for Python, but there is one in Ruby that should give you a general concept- https://github.com/iron-io/ironmq-openshift-quickstart

You can also read our blogpost about the topic- http://www.iron.io/blog/2013/02/ironio-openshift-paas-20-for-enterprise.html